# Sending SPI signals to the Flash Memory through verilog FPGA controller, but not receiving anything from it, why does it happens?

Tags: fpga, verilog, flash, synthesis

As a school project I want to write a very simple controller for a flash memory in a IC board. The FPGA chip is Altera 5CEFA4F23C8 and the flash is MX25L3206E.

I did an effort to produce the SCLK, SI and other signals that the chip needs through verilog, respecting the timing etc. I conceived the controller as a finite state machine that suppose to generate the SPI signals in order.

I have loaded the system to the board but it is not receiving anything from SO as I thought it would do automatically.

I'm using a "testbench-like" module that produce the avalon control, address and data signals like  write, read and address, for a future implementation on a larger Avalon communication protocol SoC.

I'm adding the code I write for your reference.

```
    module FLASH_CTL (

 ////////////// avalon interface///////////////////

    input   wire [23:0] avalon_slave_address,
    input   wire [3:0]  avalon_slave_byteenable,    
    input   wire        avalon_slave_read,          //             .read
    input   wire        avalon_slave_write,         //             .write
    input   wire [31:0] avalon_slave_writedata,     //             .writedata
    input   wire        reset_sink_reset,           //   reset_sink.reset
    input   wire        clock_sink_clk,             // clock_sink_1.clk

    output wire [31:0]  avalon_slave_readdata,      //             .readdata
    output wire avalon_slave_readdatavalid, //             .readdatavalid
    output wire avalon_slave_waitrequest,   //             .waitrequest


//////////////// chip interface ///////////////////
    input wire SO,  
    output reg SI,
    output reg CS,
    output wire WP,
    output wire HOLD,
    output reg SCLK 
);

parameter ST_0 = 4'd0; parameter ST_1 = 4'd1; parameter ST_2 = 4'd2; parameter ST_3 = 4'd3;  
parameter ST_4 = 4'd4; parameter ST_5 = 4'd5; parameter ST_6 = 4'd6; parameter ST_7 = 4'd7;
parameter ST_8 = 4'd8; parameter ST_9 = 4'd9; parameter ST_10 = 4'd10; parameter ST_11 = 4'd11;

parameter wr_comm = 8'b0000_0010; // PROGRAM  0X02, write 0000_0010
parameter rd_comm = 8'b0000_0011; // PROGRAM  0X03, read 0000_0011


///////////////////////////////////////////////
parameter test_A = 8'b0001_1111;


reg [7:0] test_reg;


always@ (posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin
    if (~reset_sink_reset)
        test_reg <= 0;
    else 
        test_reg <= test_A;
end

////////////////////////////////////////////



reg [31:0] av_wrdata;
reg f_cyc_count, enable, rd_SO, f_bit_count, wr_mode, word_ak, clear_byte_c; 
reg av_rd7, av_rd6, av_rd5, av_rd4, av_rd3, av_rd2, av_rd1, av_rd0;
reg [3:0] state, nextstate;
reg [4:0] cyc_count, byte_count;
reg [7:0] comm_in, data_in, av_rd_byte1, av_rd_byte2, av_rd_byte3, av_rd_byte4;
reg [23:0] addr_in;
reg [4:0] bit_count;
wire [7:0] av_rd_buff;
reg [2:0] bytes_enabled;
wire burstcount, debugaccess; 

assign WP = 1;
assign HOLD = 1;
assign avalon_slave_waitrequest = ~ CS;
assign avalon_slave_readdatavalid = (CS && state >= 1 && wr_mode)? 1'b1:1'b0;
assign avalon_slave_readdata = {av_rd_byte1, av_rd_byte2, av_rd_byte3, av_rd_byte4};
assign av_rd_buff = {av_rd7, av_rd6, av_rd5, av_rd4, av_rd3, av_rd2, av_rd1, av_rd0}; 
assign burstcount = 0;
assign debugaccess = 0;


always@ (posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset)begin
if (~reset_sink_reset)
    bytes_enabled <= 1;
else begin
    bytes_enabled <= bytes_enabled;
    case (avalon_slave_byteenable)
        4'b0001:    bytes_enabled <= 3'd0;
        4'b0011:    bytes_enabled <= 3'd1;
        4'b0111:    bytes_enabled <= 3'd2;
        4'b1111:    bytes_enabled <= 3'd3;
        default:    bytes_enabled <= bytes_enabled;
    endcase
end
end

always@ (posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset)
if (~reset_sink_reset)
    state <= ST_0;
else 
    state <= nextstate;


always@ (*) begin
CS <= 0; SI <= 0; SCLK <= 0; f_bit_count <= 0; f_cyc_count <= 0; rd_SO <= 0; word_ak <= 0; clear_byte_c <= 0;
case (state)
ST_0:   begin
            if (enable) begin
            nextstate <= ST_1;
            CS <= 0;
            end
            else begin
            nextstate <= ST_0;
            CS <= 1;
            end
        end

ST_1:   begin
            SI <= 0;  // dont care
            SCLK <= 1;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 0;
                    nextstate <= ST_2;
            end
            else begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 1;
                    nextstate <= ST_1;
            end
        end

ST_2:   begin                                       ///// send command
            SI <= comm_in [7 - bit_count];
            SCLK <= 0;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 0;
                    nextstate <= ST_3;
            end
            else begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 1;
                    nextstate <= ST_2;
            end
        end

ST_3:   begin
            SI <= comm_in [7 - bit_count];
            SCLK <= 1;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                f_cyc_count <= 0;
                f_bit_count <= 1;
                if (bit_count == 7) begin
                    nextstate <= ST_4;
                    word_ak <= 1;
                    clear_byte_c <= 1;
                end
                else begin
                    clear_byte_c <= 0;
                    nextstate = ST_2;
                    word_ak <= 0;
                end
            end
            else begin
                word_ak <= 0;
                f_bit_count <= 0;
                f_cyc_count <= 1;
                nextstate <= ST_3;
            end
        end

ST_4:   begin                                           ///// send address
            SI <= addr_in [23 - bit_count];
            SCLK <= 0;
            f_bit_count <= 0;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 0;
                    nextstate <= ST_5;
            end
            else begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 1;
                    nextstate <= ST_4;
            end
        end


ST_5:   begin
            SI <= addr_in [23 - bit_count];
            SCLK <= 1;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                f_cyc_count <= 0;
                f_bit_count <= 1;
                if (bit_count == 23) begin
                    word_ak <= 1;
                    clear_byte_c <= 1;
                    if (wr_mode)
                    nextstate = ST_6;
                    else 
                    nextstate = ST_9;
                end
                else begin 
                    clear_byte_c <= 0;
                    nextstate = ST_4;
                    word_ak <= 0;
                end
            end
            else begin
                    word_ak <= 0;
                    f_cyc_count <= 1;
                    nextstate <= ST_5;
            end
        end

ST_6:   begin                                   /// write  
            SI <= data_in [7 - bit_count];
            SCLK <= 0;
            f_bit_count <= 0;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                f_cyc_count <= 0;
                nextstate <= ST_7;
            end
            else begin
                f_cyc_count <= 1;
                nextstate <= ST_6;
            end
        end

ST_7:   begin
            SI <= data_in [7 - bit_count];      
            SCLK <= 1;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                f_cyc_count <= 0;
                f_bit_count <= 1;
                if (bit_count == 7) begin
                    word_ak <= 1;
                    if (byte_count == bytes_enabled) begin
                        clear_byte_c <= 1;
                        nextstate <= ST_8;
                    end
                    else begin              
                        clear_byte_c <= 0;
                        nextstate <= ST_6;
                    end
                end
                else begin
                    clear_byte_c <= 0;
                    word_ak <= 0;
                    nextstate = ST_6;
                end
            end
            else begin
                clear_byte_c <= 0;
                word_ak <= 0;
                f_bit_count <= 0;
                f_cyc_count <= 1;
                nextstate <= ST_7;
            end
        end 

ST_8:   begin
            rd_SO <= 0;
            CS <= 1;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 0;
                    nextstate <= ST_0;
            end
            else begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 1;
                    nextstate <= ST_8;
            end
        end

///////     
ST_9:   begin
            rd_SO <= 0;                     // read 
            SI <= 0;
            SCLK <= 0;
            f_bit_count <= 0;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 0;
                    nextstate <= ST_10;
            end
            else begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 1;
                    nextstate <= ST_9;
            end
        end

ST_10:  begin
            rd_SO <= 1;
            SI <= 0;  // dont care
            SCLK <= 1;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                f_cyc_count <= 0;
                f_bit_count <= 1;
                if (bit_count == 7) begin
                    word_ak <= 1;
                    if (byte_count == bytes_enabled) begin
                        clear_byte_c <= 1;
                        nextstate <= ST_11;
                    end
                    else begin              
                        clear_byte_c <= 0;
                        nextstate <= ST_9;
                    end
                end
                else begin
                    clear_byte_c <= 0;
                    word_ak <= 0;
                    nextstate = ST_9;
                end
            end
            else begin
                clear_byte_c <= 0;
                word_ak <= 0;
                f_bit_count <= 0;
                f_cyc_count <= 1;
                nextstate <= ST_10;
            end
        end


ST_11:  begin
            rd_SO <= 0;
            CS <= 1;
            if (cyc_count == 10) begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 0;
                    nextstate <= ST_0;
            end
            else begin
                    f_cyc_count <= 1;
                    nextstate <= ST_11;
            end
        end

default: begin
            CS <= 0; SI <= 0; SCLK <= 0; f_bit_count <= 0; f_cyc_count <= 0; nextstate <= ST_0;
            rd_SO <= 0; clear_byte_c <= 0;
         end
endcase
end

always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset)    begin
    if (~reset_sink_reset) begin
        av_rd7 <= 0; av_rd6 <= 0; av_rd5 <= 0; av_rd4 <= 0;
        av_rd3 <= 0;av_rd2 <= 0;av_rd1 <= 0;av_rd0 <= 0;
    end
    else if (rd_SO) begin
        av_rd7 <= av_rd7; av_rd6 <= av_rd6; av_rd5 <= av_rd5; av_rd4 <= av_rd4;
        av_rd3 <= av_rd3; av_rd2 <= av_rd2; av_rd1 <= av_rd1; av_rd0 <= av_rd0;     
        case (bit_count)
            0:  av_rd7 <= SO;
            1:  av_rd6 <= SO;
            2:  av_rd5 <= SO;
            3:  av_rd4 <= SO;
            4:  av_rd3 <= SO;
            5:  av_rd2 <= SO;
            6:  av_rd1 <= SO;
            7:  av_rd0 <= SO;
            default: begin 
                        av_rd7 <= av_rd7; av_rd6 <= av_rd6; av_rd5 <= av_rd5; av_rd4 <= av_rd4;
                        av_rd3 <= av_rd3; av_rd2 <= av_rd2; av_rd1 <= av_rd1; av_rd0 <= av_rd0;
                    end
        endcase
    end
    else if (CS && state >= 1) begin
        av_rd7 <= 0; av_rd6 <= 0; av_rd5 <= 0; av_rd4 <= 0;
        av_rd3 <= 0;av_rd2 <= 0;av_rd1 <= 0;av_rd0 <= 0; 
    end
    else begin
        av_rd7 <= av_rd7; av_rd6 <= av_rd6; av_rd5 <= av_rd5; av_rd4 <= av_rd4;
        av_rd3 <= av_rd3; av_rd2 <= av_rd2; av_rd1 <= av_rd1; av_rd0 <= av_rd0; 
    end

end     

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin      // DESASOCIAR BIT_COUNT DE CYCLE COUNTER
    if (~reset_sink_reset) 
        bit_count <= 0;
    else if (word_ak)
        bit_count <= 0; 
    else if (f_bit_count) 
        bit_count <= bit_count + 4'b1;
    else 
        bit_count <= bit_count;
end


always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin
    if (~reset_sink_reset) 
        cyc_count <= 0;
    else if (f_cyc_count)
        cyc_count <= cyc_count + 4'b1;
    else 
        cyc_count <= 0;
end

always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin
    if (~reset_sink_reset) 
        byte_count <= 0;
    else if (CS && state >= 1)
        byte_count <= 0;    
    else if (clear_byte_c)
        byte_count <= 0;    
    else if (word_ak)
        byte_count <= byte_count + 4'b1;
    else 
        byte_count <= byte_count;       
end     

//////////////// Controls enable from write and read /////////////////////

always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin
    if (~reset_sink_reset)
        enable <= 0;
    else if (avalon_slave_write || avalon_slave_read)
        enable <= 1;
    else 
        enable <= 0;
end     

////// controls write vs read order, with priority write /////////////////

always@ (posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin
    if (~reset_sink_reset)
        wr_mode <= 0;
    else if (avalon_slave_write)
        wr_mode <= 1;
    else if (CS && state >= 1) 
        wr_mode <= 0;
    else 
        wr_mode <= wr_mode;
end     
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin    
    if (~reset_sink_reset)
        comm_in <= rd_comm;
    else if (avalon_slave_write)             
        comm_in <= wr_comm;
    else if (avalon_slave_read)
        comm_in <= rd_comm;
    else 
        comm_in <= comm_in;
end

always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin    
    if (~reset_sink_reset) 
        addr_in <= 0;
    else if (avalon_slave_write || avalon_slave_read )             
        addr_in <= avalon_slave_address;
    else  
        addr_in <= addr_in;
end 



always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin    
    if (~reset_sink_reset) 
        av_wrdata <= 0;
    else if (avalon_slave_write || avalon_slave_read )             
        av_wrdata <= avalon_slave_writedata;
    else  
        av_wrdata <= av_wrdata;
end



always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset) begin    
    if (~reset_sink_reset) 
        data_in <= avalon_slave_writedata [7:0];
    else
    case (byte_count)              
        0:  data_in <= av_wrdata [7:0];
        1:  data_in <= av_wrdata[15:8];
        2:  data_in <= av_wrdata [23:16];
        3:  data_in <= av_wrdata [31:24];
        default: data_in <= av_wrdata [7:0];
    endcase

end 



///////// Gather all 4 bytes in 1 register ////////////////////////

always@(posedge  clock_sink_clk or negedge reset_sink_reset)    begin
    if (~reset_sink_reset) begin
        av_rd_byte1 <= 0; av_rd_byte2 <= 0; av_rd_byte3 <= 0; av_rd_byte4 <= 0;
    end
    else if (clear_byte_c && state >= ST_10) begin
        av_rd_byte1 <= av_rd_byte1; av_rd_byte2 <= av_rd_byte2; av_rd_byte3 <= av_rd_byte3; av_rd_byte4 <= av_rd_byte4;
        case (byte_count)
            0:  av_rd_byte1 <= av_rd_buff;
            1:  av_rd_byte2 <= av_rd_buff;
            2:  av_rd_byte3 <= av_rd_buff;
            3:  av_rd_byte4 <= av_rd_buff;
            default: begin 
                        av_rd7 <= av_rd7; av_rd6 <= av_rd6; av_rd5 <= av_rd5; av_rd4 <= av_rd4;
                        av_rd3 <= av_rd3; av_rd2 <= av_rd2; av_rd1 <= av_rd1; av_rd0 <= av_rd0;
                    end
        endcase
    end
    else if (CS && state >= 1) begin
        av_rd_byte1 <= 0; av_rd_byte2 <= 0; av_rd_byte3 <= 0; av_rd_byte4 <= 0;
    end
end


endmodule
```

The top module is this

```
        module FLASH_CTL_TOP (

        input   wire    sys_rst,           //   reset_sink.reset
        input   wire    sys_clk,             // clock_sink_1.clk

    //////////////// chip interface ///////////////////
        input wire SO,  
        output wire SI,
        output wire CS,
        output wire WP,
        output wire HOLD,
        output wire SCLK ,
        output reg led
    );


        reg [23:0]  avalon_slave_address;// avalon_slave.address    ?????????????????????????
        reg [3:0]   avalon_slave_byteenable;    //             .byteenable
        reg avalon_slave_read;          //             .read
        reg avalon_slave_write;         //             .write
        reg [31:0]  avalon_slave_writedata;     //             .writedata
        reg [14:0] tb_count;

        wire [31:0] avalon_slave_readdata;      //             .readdata
        wire avalon_slave_readdatavalid; //             .readdatavalid
        wire avalon_slave_waitrequest;   //             .waitrequest
        wire debugaccess, burstcount;

        assign burstcount = 0;
        assign debugaccess = 0;

        reg [31:0] led_counter;






/*
    flash_qsys u0  (
        .clk_clk             (sys_clk),             //   clk.clk
        .reset_reset_n       (sys_rst),       // reset.reset_n

        .end_cs              (CS),              //   end.cs
        .end_si              (SI),              //      .si
        .end_so              (SO),              //      .so
        .end_wp              (WP),              //      .wp
        .end_sclk            (SCLK),            //      .sclk
        .end_hold            (HOLD),            //      .hold

        .sobus_waitrequest   (avalon_slave_waitrequest),   // sobus.waitrequest
        .sobus_readdata      (avalon_slave_readdata),      //      .readdata
        .sobus_readdatavalid (avalon_slave_readdatavalid), //      .readdatavalid

        .sobus_burstcount    (burstcount),    //      .burstcount
        .sobus_writedata     (avalon_slave_writedata),     //      .writedata
        .sobus_address       (avalon_slave_address),       //      .address
        .sobus_write         (avalon_slave_write),         //      .write
        .sobus_read          (avalon_slave_read),          //      .read
        .sobus_byteenable    (avalon_slave_byteenable),    //      .byteenable
        .sobus_debugaccess   (debugaccess)    //      .debugaccess
    );

*/


FLASH_CTL FLASH_CTL_inst1 (
.SO (SO),
.SI (SI),
.CS(CS),
.WP(WP),
.HOLD(HOLD),
.SCLK(SCLK),

.avalon_slave_address (avalon_slave_address),
.avalon_slave_byteenable (avalon_slave_byteenable),   
.avalon_slave_read (avalon_slave_read),          
.avalon_slave_write (avalon_slave_write ),         
.avalon_slave_writedata (avalon_slave_writedata),    
.reset_sink_reset (sys_rst),          
.clock_sink_clk (sys_clk),            

.avalon_slave_readdata (avalon_slave_readdata),      
.avalon_slave_readdatavalid (avalon_slave_readdatavalid), 
.avalon_slave_waitrequest (avalon_slave_waitrequest)   

);  


always@(posedge sys_clk or negedge sys_rst) begin
    if (~sys_rst) begin
        led <= 1;
        led_counter <= 0;
    end
    else if (led_counter == 31'd100_000_000) begin
        led <= 0;
        led_counter <= led_counter + 16'b1;;
    end
    else if (led_counter == 31'd200_000_000) begin
        led <= 1;
        led_counter <= 0;
    end

    else begin
        led <= led; 
        led_counter <= led_counter + 16'b1;
    end
end



always@(posedge sys_clk  or negedge sys_rst) begin
    if (~sys_rst) begin
        avalon_slave_read <= 0;
        avalon_slave_write <= 0;
        avalon_slave_address <= 0;
        avalon_slave_writedata <= 0;
        avalon_slave_byteenable <= 0;
    end
    else if (tb_count == 200) begin
        avalon_slave_write <= 1;
        avalon_slave_read <= 0;
        avalon_slave_address <= 24'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011;  //// 24'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011
        avalon_slave_writedata <= 32'b1010_1010_1010_0000__0000_0000_0000_0011; //8'b1000_0101
        avalon_slave_byteenable <= 4'b1111;

    end
    else if (tb_count == 2000) begin
        avalon_slave_read <= 1;
        avalon_slave_write <= 0;
        avalon_slave_address <= 24'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011; //// 24'b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011
        avalon_slave_writedata <= 32'b0000_0000_0000_0000__0000_0000_0000_0000; // 8'b0000_0000
        avalon_slave_byteenable <= 4'b1111;
    end
    else begin
        avalon_slave_byteenable <= 0;
        avalon_slave_read <= 0;
        avalon_slave_write <= 0;
        avalon_slave_address <= 0;
        avalon_slave_writedata <= 0;
    end
end

always@ (posedge sys_clk or negedge sys_rst) begin
    if (~sys_rst) 
        tb_count <= 0;
    else if (tb_count == 3000)
        tb_count <= tb_count;
    else 
        tb_count <= tb_count + 15'b1;
end 





endmodule
```

[image]

[image]

The code is basically running as expected (as far as I know) as it can be seen in the second attached imag, but I'm receiving this "1" from the SO pin from the beginning of the time without changes, so I'm not able to pick up the "supposedly" data from SO.

any thoughts about this? Chip might be malfunctioning?

[image]

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: @TimB thanks, what would you suggest? I need to know what's wrong with the code, why is not working? I don't have idea how to translate this question into the rules of the website.

Comment: You have put up over 650 lines of Verilog code and that is without the test bench. You can't expect us to just 'check' that. You also say that  *it is not outputting anything from SO* but SO is an input.

Comment: @oldfart I meant to say outputting from chip (to the FPGA), I'm inputting signals to the chip, but not receiving the outputted response from the chip.

Comment: I suggest debugging and asking a specific question. We are not here to debug your problems. The site is for asking specific questions relevant to all, and receiving well written answers that can be useful for others. You neither have a specific question, nor a question which an answer could be used to help someone in the future. Instead you have phrased a “please fix my code” request in the form of a question.

Comment: @TimB Ok I'm editing the question as good as I can. Thanks.

Comment: Then please edit it here and don’t spam the site with duplicate questions. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353387/signal-tap-ii-reading-a-1-from-so-of-flash-chip-always-from-the-beginning-wi

Comment: You got a lot unnecessary `flop <= flop;` statements. They don't do anything unless it was assigned to something earlier. Also combinational logic should use blocking (`=`) assignments, not non-blocking (`<=`). Neither will change your codes behavior but it would make it more readable and concise. Be aware that most FPGA have a limited number of flops with asynchronous resets, if any. I don't know about the Altera 5CEFA4F23C8 specifically, but you may want to use synchronous resets instead.

Comment: *"I have loaded the system to the board but it is not receiving anything from SO"* ... and what your system is sending on SI? Maybe you should check this first.

Comment: @Greg, this comes up often on this site. By volumes sold, most FPGAs have an asynchronous reset per register, making asynchronous resets far more efficient in those devices. Drive them with an asynchronously asserted, synchronously negated, reset source circuit. Synchronous resets in such devices use up LUTs and increase path routing delay. Thing is to always check your target device architecture in the data sheet and design your HDL accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why your trace doesn't have SI signaling? A SPI Flash memory is not a simple device, it needs status checking and likely some mode selection commands to start operating. Where is CS# in your traces? What is HOLD# status? From datasheet:

> DEVICE OPERATION
>
> 1.Before a command is issued, status register should be checked to ensure device is ready for the intended operation.
>
> 2.When incorrect command is inputted to this device, it enters standby mode and remains in standby mode until next  CS#  falling  edge.  In 
>   standby  mode,  SO  pin  of  the  device  is  High-Z.  The  CS# 
>   falling  time  needs  to  follow  tCHCL spec.
>
> 3.When  correct  command  is  inputted  to  this  device,  it  enters  active  mode  and  remains  in  active  mode  until  next  CS# rising
>   edge. The CS# rising time needs to follow tCLCH spec.
>
> 4.Input data is latched on the rising edge of Serial Clock(SCLK) and data is shifted out on the falling edge of SCLK. The difference of
>   Serial mode 0 and mode 3 is shown in Figure 1.
>
> 5.For  the  following  instructions:  RDID,  RDSR,  RDSCUR,  READ,  FAST_READ,  RDSFDP, DREAD,  RES,  and  REMS the shifted-in instruction
>   sequence is followed by a data-out sequence. After any bit of data
>   being shifted out,  the  CS#  can  be  high.  For  the  following 
>   instructions:  WREN,  WRDI,  WRSR,  SE,  BE,  CE,  PP,  RDP,  DP, 
>   ENSO, EXSO, and  WRSCUR, the CS# must go high exactly at the byte
>   boundary; otherwise, the instruction will be rejected and not
>   executed.
>
> 6.While  a  Write  Status  Register,  Program,  or  Erase  operation  is  in  progress,  access  to  the  memory  array  is  neglected and
>   will not affect the current operation of Write Status Register,
>   Program, Erase

Which command are you sending to your memory chip?

Comment: Sorry I did not included the SI and CS signals in the picture of the wave, I'm updating those pictures now. I'm sending the WRITE ENABLE (06h) and the WRITE COMMAND (02H). The problem is that chip does not seems to care any command I send, since start up is outputting "1". I'm thinking it is on stand by mode but WRITE ENABLE should take it out from it, but there is nothing that make it change. So I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @user176257 Does any of your sequential CS#-CLK-SI data resemble timing diagrams shown in Figures 7 - etc. etc. of the IC datasheet? http://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/6665/MX25L3206E,%203V,%2032Mb,%20v1.5.pdf

Comment: I tried to send the CS, CLK and SI signal as described in the Datasheet, even taking care of the timming, altough I don't know if I do it correctly. The last attached image I'm sending 9Fh command for reading chip ID. Nothing comeout from the SO except 1 perpetually. You can observe also that reset is a routed to a button in the board I'm working, the reset is naturally 0, then I press become 1 but because the time is very short, signal tap ii screening shows it still at 1 and starting the FSM.

Comment: @user176257, "even taking care of the timming" sounds like a dangerous sloppiness. I think you violate timing for assertion of CS# relative to CLK, see Figure 7. More, max READ speed is 33 MHz, while your clock seems to be 45 MHz (22 ns). Take a second read of datasheets. You are still not plotting HOLD# and WP# signals. We are not interested in your state machine internals, only the real output is important to the issue.

Comment: I finally made the chip to talk back to me with the command 05h, I was making a mistake indeed with the timming SCLK is half period forward than it should, I fixed it and at least I know the chip is working good. Thank you. I wish to select your answer as best but I'm new, I'll do it once I can.

Comment: By the way, I'm not violating the timming otherwise 9Fh would not work sending back the RDID C2 - 20 - 16.

Comment: @user176257 Violating the chip specifications is not a guarantee of any particular failure mode, just failure in general. So saying "would not work" is presumptuous: how do you know that the memory chip will misbehave exactly that way? You usually don't and can't. Timing  violations are not *guaranteed* to make things not work! They are usually only guaranteed to cause problems when the circumstances conspire to make failures annoying and expensive :)